# Conditional Branching Using Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using multiple jQuery filter functions to affect the background color of select objects based on the selected option and it works, but it seems bulky/redundant. Does anyone know how these filter statements could be simplified/combined? I have a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kn1ghtman/RDEeA/).

```
<head>

<!-- Load minimum jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load functions -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- jQuery Functions -->
  $(document).ready(function(){
/* Add 'Contracted' title and change background to green (if not already red) for 'C' services */
    $("select").parent()
    .filter(function(index){
        return $(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'C'; })
    .attr('title','Contracted')
    .addClass(function(index,currentClass) {
        var addedClass;
        if ( currentClass != "cellcolorred" )
            { addedClass = "cellcolorgreen"; }
        return addedClass;
    });
/* Add 'Available' title and change background to green (if not already red) for 'A' services */
    $("select").parent()
    .filter(function(index){
        return $(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'A'; })
    .attr('title','Available')
    .addClass(function(index,currentClass) {
        var addedClass;
        if ( currentClass != "cellcolorred" )
            { addedClass = "cellcolorgreen"; }
        return addedClass;
    });
/* Add 'Expensive' title and change background to orange (if not already red) for 'E' services */
    $("select").parent()
    .filter(function(index){
        return $(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'E'; })
    .attr('title','Expensive')
    .addClass(function(index,currentClass) {
        var addedClass;
        if ( currentClass != "cellcolorred" )
            { addedClass = "cellcolororange"; }
        return addedClass;
    });
/* Add 'Do Not Use' title and change background to pink for 'D' services */
    $("select").parent()
    .filter(function(index){
        return $(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'D'; })
    .attr('title','Do Not Use')
    .addClass("cellcolorpink");
/* Add 'No Service' title to empty services */
    $("select").parent()
    .filter(function(index){
        return $(this).find('option:selected').text() == ''; })
    .attr('title','No Service');
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

/* body */
    body {
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #A3AFC0;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    select::-ms-expand { display: none; }
    select {
        appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: window;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border-style: none;
        background: none;
        color: inherit;
        width: inherit;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font: inherit;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-indent: 11.5px;
    } /* Select Cells */
    tbody {
        border-bottom-width: 2px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }
    tbody:last-of-type { border-bottom-width: 1px; }
    tbody:nth-child(even) { background-color: #E1E1E1; }
    tbody:hover td[rowspan], tr:hover td { background-color: #FF0; }
    td {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: inherit;
    }
/* tfoot */
    tfoot {
        border-width: 1px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #E1E1E1;
    }
/* Classes */
/* table */
    .tablesorter {
        table-layout: fixed;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-color: #6E7984;
    }

/* header */
    .tablesorter th,
    .tablesorter thead td {
        height: 24px;
        text-shadow: 0 0 4px #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 11px;
        background-color: #22A5C9 !important;
        padding: 0;
    }
/* tbody */
    .tablesorter td {
        text-align: center;
        width: 33.5px;
    }

    .cellcolorred {
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #F00 !important;
    }
    .cellcolorgreen { background-color: #CFC !important; }
    .cellcolororange { background-color: #FC9 !important; }
    .cellcolorpink { background-color: #FCC !important; }
</style>

  </head>
<!-- Body -->
  <body>
<!-- Table -->
  <table border="1" class="tablesorter" id="table-1">
<!-- Table Header -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Alarm</td>
            <td>Bflow</td>
            <td>Burg</td>
            <td>ELt</td>
            <td>Eng</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<!-- Table Footer -->
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='100%'>1 Location</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
<!-- Table Body -->
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td>AL08960</td>
            <td id="Alarm">
                <select>
                <option selected>C</option>
                <option>A</option>
                <option>E</option>
                <option disabled>-</option>
                <option>D</option>
                <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="Bflow">
                <select>
                <option>C</option>
                <option selected>A</option>
                <option>E</option>
                <option disabled>-</option>
                <option>D</option>
                <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="Burg">
                <select>
                <option>C</option>
                <option>A</option>
                <option>E</option>
                <option disabled>-</option>
                <option>D</option>
                <option selected></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="ELt">
                <select>
                <option>C</option>
                <option>A</option>
                <option selected>E</option>
                <option disabled>-</option>
                <option>D</option>
                <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td id="Eng">
                <select>
                <option>C</option>
                <option>A</option>
                <option>E</option>
                <option disabled>-</option>
                <option selected>D</option>
                <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 <table id="header-fixed"></table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to overuse `!important` in your CSS. This is very bad, but I didn't change anything about this.

Your script is extremely repetitive, too. I tried my hand at DRYing it and I got:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var serviceStatuses = {
        'A': {
            title: "Available",
            color: "green"
        },
        'C': {
            title: "Contracted",
            color: "green"
        },
        'D': {
            title: "Do Not Use",
            color: "pink",
            override: true
        },
        'E': {
            title: "Expensive",
            color: "orange"
        }
    };
    $("select").each(function() {
        var $t = $(this);
        var $td = $t.parent();
        var status = serviceStatuses[$t.val()] || {
            title: "No Service",
            color: "Default"
        };
        $td.attr("title", status.title).toggleClass("cellcolor" + status.color, status.override || !$td.hasClass("cellcolorred"));
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWsg6/2/) demonstrating it. I took the liberty of adding another row with `cellcolorred` on every cell to demonstrate that `D` will still override the selection.

Comment: That worked perfect! I took out the override code, because, as I explained in my comment to Alex L, cellcolorred would only be set for A, C, or E cells if the row is considered inactive, so a 'D' cell would never have a cellcolorred class on it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Because there's no context to your code, and it's difficult to understand what the purpose is, I couldn't do much besides refactor the code. I was hoping I would be able to suggest alternate methods to get the job done, but I didn't feel I had enough info.

### JavaScript

I was able to DRY it out and come up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function selector(text, newTitle, newClass) {
        $("select").parent().filter(function () {
            return $(this).find('option:selected').text() == text;
        }).attr('title', newTitle).addClass(newClass);
    }
    selector('C', 'Contracted', function (index, currentClass) {
        return (currentClass != 'cellcolorred') ? 'cellcolorgreen' : '';
    });
    selector('A', 'Available', function (index, currentClass) {
        return (currentClass != 'cellcolorred') ? 'cellcolorgreen' : '';
    });
    selector('E', 'Expensive', function (index, currentClass) {
        return (currentClass != 'cellcolorred') ? 'cellcolororange' : '';
    });
    selector('D', 'Do Not Use', 'cellcolorpink');
    selector('', 'No Service', null);
});
```

This is exactly a third of what you originally presented, however I feel even this could be brought down a notch.

You'll notice I stuck the repeating code in a function, and was able to pass the class as a closure. This allows for easier expansion and reduction.

I'm confused about the conditional though, because to start off, none of the cells have a class. So I'm not sure why you check if they're `cellcolorred` because they all fail the condition, therefore coloring it.

### HTML

Not too much to comment on. It's pretty simple and nothing is too complex.

- I don't see a need to ID the table. You never refer to the ID, and if you do need to reference, the class should work fine.
- `table#header-fixed` has no use in the code at all. Maybe you just left out that context.

### CSS

- Not sure why you set `border: 0` on the `body`. The body doesn't have a border in the first place.
- In the `select`s, it's difficult to there they're actually buttons with the `appearance` set to none. Perhaps add a `cursor` or pronounce their button-ness more.
- Clean up `tbody`:

  > ```
  > border-bottom-width: 2px;
  > border-bottom-style: solid;
  > ```

  to

  ```
    border-bottom: 2px auto solid;
  ```
- I think it's easier to read something such as:

  ```
   tr .red {
  ```

  as opposed to

  > ```
  > .cellcolorred {
  > ```

  I suggest you clean up these types of things. Hopefully you'll be able to find a better name than `red` of course!

Comment: This code is only a relevant chunk of a full table that's viewed through a web viewer in FileMaker. Without going too far into it, it shows data from 3 different data tables, each one step down from the previous, in each row. The reason for cellcolorred is to highlight when a record is inactive, but a service is active. A, C, & E are usable statuses, but 'D' means Do Not Use. If the row is inactive and the status is usable, I set cellcolorred. With the selects not looking like buttons, that was intentional. This replaced a native portal, so I tried to emulate the appearance as best I could.